# One Signal API - programmatically add device

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am currently using the onesignal API to send push notifications. what i observed is that the device is automatically subscribed for push notifications. I don't want that , i want to be able to add the device so as to get the player id and send them notifications.

The challenge is when the app launches , how can i get access to the subscription details from one signal API.

many thanks.

Comment: im confused. the app launches, they subscribe. you dont want that. but you want to add the device id to send them notifications. you cant send them notifications if they do not subscribe to a channel

Comment: i want to be the one to subscribe them instead of one signal subscribing them immediately when the app launches. do you get ?

Comment: well, you can create a few channels. when they sign up, it will subscribe them to 'all'. then you can have a setting pages within the app where the user can unsub to certain pushes....etc. this is the route i went with

Comment: after more digging, i got to use onesignal.getIds().then(data=>{});

Answer (score 0):

Since OneSignal is auto-subscribing on the first run. You should unsubscribe it after it does that. Example, the app runs, OneSignal initializes, therefore you should unsubscribe it by:

```
OneSignal.setSubscription(false)
```

then subscribe again by: `OneSignal.setSubscription(true)`.

For ionic use:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
```